# No capture devices found in FMJ

Tags: java, jmf, fmj

Previously I was working with JMF, but JMF need to be installed, but I don't want to add this overhead. That's why I want be moved to FMJ. And FMJ is opensource. :)

There is some sample example given with FMJ source. And there is a FMJStudio, from where I can run and transmit RTP audio captured from microphone.

But when I want to Transmit RTP, using the source below, it couldn't find any capture device.

The complete source can be found on: **fmj-20070928-0938_2.zip** in [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net) 
And the class name of this source class is **SimpleVoiceTransmiter**.

```
    //final String urlStr = URLUtils.createUrlStr(new File("samplemedia/gulp2.wav"));//"file://samplemedia/gulp2.wav";
    Format format;

    format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.ULAW_RTP, 8000, 8, 1);
    //format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.ULAW_RTP, 8000.0, 8, 1, AudioFormat.LITTLE_ENDIAN, AudioFormat.SIGNED);
    //format = new AudioFormat(BonusAudioFormatEncodings.ALAW_RTP, 8000, 8, 1);
    //format = new AudioFormat(BonusAudioFormatEncodings.SPEEX_RTP, 8000, 8, 1, -1, AudioFormat.SIGNED);
    //format = new AudioFormat(BonusAudioFormatEncodings.ILBC_RTP, 8000.0, 16, 1, AudioFormat.LITTLE_ENDIAN, AudioFormat.SIGNED);

    CaptureDeviceInfo di = null;
            //Set to true if you want to transmit audio from capture device, like microphone.
    if (true)
    {
        // First find a capture device that will capture linear audio
        // data at 8bit 8Khz
        AudioFormat captureFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR, 8000, 8, 1);

        Vector devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(captureFormat);



        if (devices.size() > 0)
        {
            di = (CaptureDeviceInfo) devices.elementAt(0);
        } else
        {
            System.err.println("No capture devices");
            // exit if we could not find the relevant capturedevice.
            System.exit(-1);

        }
    }

    // Create a processor for this capturedevice & exit if we
    // cannot create it
    Processor processor = null;
    try
    {
        //processor = Manager.createProcessor(new MediaLocator(urlStr));
                    processor = Manager.createProcessor(di.getLocator());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (NoProcessorException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // configure the processor
    processor.configure();

    while (processor.getState() != Processor.Configured)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    processor.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW_RTP));

    TrackControl track[] = processor.getTrackControls();

    boolean encodingOk = false;

    // Go through the tracks and try to program one of them to
    // output g.711 data.

    for (int i = 0; i < track.length; i++)
    {
        if (!encodingOk && track[i] instanceof FormatControl)
        {
            if (((FormatControl) track[i]).setFormat(format) == null)
            {

                track[i].setEnabled(false);
            } else
            {
                encodingOk = true;
            }
        } else
        {
            // we could not set this track to g.711, so disable it
            track[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    // At this point, we have determined where we can send out
    // g.711 data or not.
    // realize the processor
    if (encodingOk)
    {
        if (!new net.sf.fmj.ejmf.toolkit.util.StateWaiter(processor).blockingRealize())
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to realize");
            return;
        }

        // get the output datasource of the processor and exit
        // if we fail
        DataSource ds = null;

        try
        {
            ds = processor.getDataOutput();
        } catch (NotRealizedError e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // hand this datasource to manager for creating an RTP
        // datasink our RTP datasink will multicast the audio
        try
        {
            String url = "rtp://192.168.1.99:49150/audio/1";

            MediaLocator m = new MediaLocator(url);

            DataSink d = Manager.createDataSink(ds, m);
            d.open();
            d.start();

            System.out.println("Starting processor");
            processor.start();
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

When I run this source, The output is: **No capture devices**

What may be the problem? :-(

Edit: I uninstalled the **JMF** from my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after two and half days, stuck in the middle of nowhere, I pointed out the problem myself.

The problem was, when I uninstalled **JMF** it wasn't removed from the **CLASSPATH** user variable. There was  somethinng like:

```
  "C:\PROGRA~1\JMF21~1.1E\lib\sound.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\JMF21~1.1E\lib\jmf.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\JMF21~1.1E\lib;"
```

and when I removed them, and restarted my computer. Then bingo. The code run without any problem. :)